# Is it possible to track app installs using the Facebook Unity SDK without logging the user into Facebook?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I am trying to setup a Facebook marketing campaign with the objective being to track app installs. Facebook recommends using their SDK to get accurate information about app installs, but I don't want to prompt the user to login to Facebook in my app. Is it possible to have the Facebook SDK track app installs without users logging in? According to Facebook their API automatically tracks app installs but it seems that in their initialization script called mainmenu.cs requires a Facebook login to occur.

Comment: You don't need to prompt the user to login using Facebook.

Comment: You should read about Facebook SDK events: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/unity, like WizKid said, you don't need the user logged in to track app activations and other events, log in being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was basically create a persistent game object in my first scene and attached this code to it. I based this code off of Facebook's example https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/unity but added some additional checks so FB.Init() would not be called twice. I also added a coroutine that would wait to activate an event until `FB.Init()` is done since `FB.Init()` is an asynchronous function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Facebook.Unity;

public class FacebookTracker : MonoBehaviour {
    private static FacebookTracker instance;
    private bool initCalled;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        } else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if (FB.IsInitialized == false && initCalled == false)
        {
            FB.Init();
            initCalled = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnApplicationPause = " + pause);
        if (pause == false)
        {
            if (FB.IsInitialized == true)
            {
                FB.ActivateApp();
            } else
            {
                if (initCalled == false)
                {
                    FB.Init();
                    initCalled = true;
                }
                StartCoroutine(ActivateEvent());
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ActivateEvent()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => FB.IsInitialized == true);
        Debug.Log("Facebook Activate Event Logged");
        FB.ActivateApp();
    }
}
```